# Detecting Object Removal in Images

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

The problem statement is as follows - Given an altered image (an image from which some object has been removed), generate a mask for the removed object.

For instance, say an original image contains three dogs. After some alteration, one of the dogs is removed from the image. Now, given the altered image, a mask should be generated for the removed dog.

I am not experienced in computer vision or image processing, so firstly, I would like to know if this problem statement even makes sense. What I could think of as a potential solution was Discontinuity Detection. However, there can be so many discontinuities in an image which are not a product of any alteration. This stumps me.

So here's a breakdown of my question into sub-questions:

1. If this problem statement makes sense, can it can be solved using classic image processing methods?
2. Can it be solved using ML/DL? Like given a set of original image, altered image, and an appropriate mask, can an NN be trained to generate a mask for a given altered image? If this is possible, how much data would be required?

As I have mentioned my inexperience in computer vision and image processing, it would be a great help if you guys could drop some references to read/watch. Thank you.